# interface builder change constraint 2nd item?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, constraints

Hi I want to change the second item of a constraint - for example a UILabel has a constraint for Top Space to Top Layout Guide - I want to change that to superview, OR, I want to change Align Trailing To: superview instead of another label - when I click on Edit I cannot change it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtAXv.jpg

If I select the constraint on the left side, if I try to edit the second item, it won't let me change it to superview here either... 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBBoe.jpg

any tips?  thanks.  read the documentation but didn't find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change things like the `constant`, `priority` or `multiplier` after creating a constraint. But you cannot change the items involved.

So you have to remove the constraint and recreate it with the correct second item.

(see *Puneet Sharma*'s answer for how to select the correct view when creating a constraint in IB)

Answer (score 0):

Press on the black arrow button. It will show you options you can align a particular constraint with in a dropdown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that sometimes you can.

1. Select your constraint from the document outline

[image: Constraint selection]

2. On successful selection you'll see the constraint in the size inspector. Open the dropdown menu of the item you want to change

[image]

3. If you can change the item from the interface builder you'll see the possible alternatives. Select the one you desire

[image]